# How to get the distinct number of the nodes?

Tags: 8, database

In my task I need to get the distinct number of the nodes of some content type. How can I do it?

```
$query = $this->connection->select('node', 'node')->condition('node.type', $type);
$query->addExpression('COUNT(*)');
$query->innerJoin('taxonomy_index', $id,  "$id.nid = node.nid  AND $id.status = 1");
$count = intval($query->execute()->fetchField());
```

As the node may have multiple values for the field, in the end it counts all nodes and produces the wrong output. Therefore I need to get distinct number of nodes.

Just adding $query->distinct(); doesn't bring anything. Could you please help me how can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve distinct number of the nodes of content type `$type`.
Try this.

```
use Drupal\Core\Database\Database;

//- Retrieves a \Drupal\Core\Database\Connection which is a PDO instance
  $connection = Database::getConnection();
    $query = $connection->select('node', 'node')
        ->fields('node', array('nid'))
        ->condition('node.type', $type, '=')
        //- Force filtering of duplicate records in the result set.
         ->distinct()
        ->countQuery()
        ->execute();

    $count = $query->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

Ps: you still have to add Your desired `innerJoin` to the query take a look to [Select::innerJoin](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21Select.php/function/Select%3A%3AinnerJoin/8.2.x) .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Drupal EntityQuery](https://www.sitepoint.com/drupal-8-version-entityfieldquery/) class like this:

```
$count = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('status', 1)
    ->condition('type', $type)
    ->count()->execute();
```

Comment: maybe I should have mentioned in the description that i perform an innerjoin as well with "taxonomy_index" table, and it results in wrong counting. That's why I am searching a way to reduce duplicates

Comment: Then please update the question and include the missing code so that others can help as well